# Invoking constructor through PIMPL idiom design

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

```
/*Process.h*/
class Process  {
    public:
    Process(ProcessID thirdParty_pid);

    protected:
    void createImpl();

    private:
    ProcessImpl  * _impl;
};


/*ProcessImpl.h*/

 class ProcessImpl {
      public :
      ProcessImpl(ProcessID thirdParty_pid);
 }
```

Using PIMPL idiom now I amtrying to invoke ProcessImpl constructor in this way:

```
Process::Process(ldframework::ProcessID tpid):_impl(ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid)) {
}
```

But I am getting following error
error: cannot convert ProcessImpl to ProcessImpl* in initialization

pls help in resolving this error and also let me know wts the correct metrhod to invoke

Comment: _impl is a pointer to ProcessImpl but you're passing a value. Change to :_impl(new ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid)) (and manage to dispose it in Process' destructor).

Answer (score 1):

Since `_impl` is a pointer, you have to initialize it with a pointer:

```
Process::Process(ldframework::ProcessID tpid)
    : _impl(new ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid))
{ ... }
```

Note the use of the `new` keyword in the initialization of `_impl`.

Answer (score 1):

`_impl` is a pointer **(PIMPL => Pointer to Implementation)**.

So, use the `new` keyword for initialization.

```
Process::Process(ldframework::ProcessID tpid)
  :_impl( new ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid)) {
}
```

But use PIMPL with `smart_pointers`, therefore, read [Sutter about compilation firewalls](http://herbsutter.com/gotw/_100/)!

Answer (score 0):

Your expression `ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid)` evaluates to type `ProcessImpl`, which is not the same as type `ProcessImpl*`, the type of your member `_impl`.

Try using `new` inside your initializer list instead, and remember `delete` in your destructor.

e.g.

```
: _impl( new ldframework::ProcessImpl::ProcessImpl(tpid) )
```

and later in your destructor

```
delete _impl;
```

Comment: Let me know wts the correct method to invoke the constructor yhrough PIMPL idiom